# Is there a good reason why `deleteBy` does not have its most general type?

Tags: haskell, frege

The Haskell 2010 Language Report states in section 20.10.1.1 that:

```
deleteBy :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> a -> [a] -> [a]
```

In fact, the implementation in the [GHC library](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/src/Data-List.html#delete) would allow

```
deleteBy :: (b -> a -> Bool) -> b -> [a] -> [a]
```

but actually restricts the type to the former one with the annotation.

Hence, one cannot say, for instance:

```
foo = deleteBy fsteq 42 [(43, "foo"), (44, "bar"), (42, "baz")] where
    fsteq a (b,_) = a == b
```

because `Int` is not the same as `(Int, String)`.

Is there any good reason for this?

The reason I am asking is that, if there is no good reason for it, I would include `deleteBy` with the more general type in the [Frege](http://code.google.com/p/frege) port of Data.List I am currently doing. But maybe I am overlooking something?

EDIT: As @hammar pointed out, this applies to other *xxx*By functions also.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Generalising the type of `deleteBy` violates the standard in a very practical way: perfectly valid Haskell programs become invalid, thanks to unresolved overloading.

Here's a demonstration:

```
class (Num a) => Magic a where
  magic :: a -> Bool

sameMagic :: (Magic a, Magic b) => a -> b -> Bool
sameMagic a b = magic a == magic b

test :: (Magic a) => [a]
test = deleteBy sameMagic 42 [1234]
```

In Haskell, this program is perfectly well-typed; `deleteBy`'s restricted type ensures that the `42` is guaranteed to have the same type as the `1234`. With the generalised `deleteBy`, this is not the case, and so the type of `42` is ambiguous, making the program invalid. (If you want a less contrived example, consider a function which compares two `Integral` values with `toInteger`.)

So, perhaps there is no good reason for this restricted type (although if `deleteBy` is to be generalised, I would prefer hammar's version to your proposal), but generalising it *does* violate the standard, and it can break valid programs.

Comment: That's the sort of insightful comments I was looking for. Gives me something to think about.

Comment: This is a very insightful answer!

Comment: But shouldn't 42 be resolved to `Integer` by type-defaulting rules?

Comment: @haskelline Lazy Polymorphism?

Answer (score 10):

I guess it's for symmetry with the other `xxxBy` functions. However, your type is still needlessly specific. I would prefer this.

```
deleteBy :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```

You could then write your example using partial application:

```
foo = deleteBy (fsteq 42) [(43, "foo"), (44, "bar"), (42, "baz")] where
    fsteq a (b,_) = a == b
```

Comment: Except that filter would delete *all* equal elements, where deleteBy must delete the first one only.

Comment: @Ingo: Oops! You're absolutely right. `filter` will not do the job here.

Comment: Sure, there are ways around it, but you see, the objective is to stick to the standard (Haskell 2010, in this case). The question being if it violates the standard if one is a bit more general.

Comment: @Ingo "Does it violate the standard if one is a bit more general"? In technicality, yes. In practicality, no (imho).

Answer (score 7):

Ingo,

in your original question, it seems you're asking why Haskell Report specifies *deleteBy* like this.
So if there's no strong reason, you could use a different definition in Frege (implying you don't care about Haskell Report conformance).

As Hammar says, it's like the other xxxBy functions: *delete* uses *(==)*,  *deleteBy* takes a predicate that is like *(==)*: of type (a -> a -> Bool) and assumed to be an equivalence relation. While the type system cannot check if the predicate is really an equivalance relation, it is the function contract. So it's very easy to understand what xxxBy means if you know what xxx means. And maybe it's not the case for deleteBy, but in some cases an implementation might be optimized under the assumption the predicate has the specified properties (equivalence relation or total order, etc).

But in your comment to Hammar's answer, you ask whether the more general implementation would violate the report. Well, if the type is different then it is literally a violation, right? Since programs that shouldn't compile according to the report will be accepted by your compiler. So it gives rise to a portability problem: if your code uses the more general version, then it might not compile on another implementation that conforms to the specification. Besides, it does away with the equivalence relation requirement.

So if you want a more general function, why not simply define another function with a different name? For instance, *deleteIf*.

(I wanted to comment on Hammar's answer, but I can't so I wrote it here.)