# Why Haskell's Data.List.deleteBy takes in input a comparison function (a -> a -> Bool) and a value instead of a predicate (a -> Bool)?

Tags: haskell

I have a question related to Data.List and the signature of [deleteBy](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v%3adeleteBy). Ideally this function should take in input a predicate and delete the first element for which the predicate is true. Something like:

```
deleteBy :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
deleteBy p = go
    where go []                   = []
          go (x:xs) | p x         = xs
                    | otherwise   = x:go xs
```

Instead the function defined in the library takes both a predicate and a value:

```
deleteBy                :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> a -> [a] -> [a]
deleteBy _  _ []        = []
deleteBy eq x (y:ys)    = if x `eq` y then ys else y : deleteBy eq x ys
```

It's easy to see that `eq` is always used with `x` as first argument and `x` is fixed in `deleteBy`, so there is no reason to get both `eq` and `x` instead of `eq x`. On contrary, by taking a predicate working on a single element you can pass predicates that don't compare two values, such as a function that works on a part of the type `a` or a trivial function like `cons true`. My question is: why `deleteBy` has been implemented in this way?

Comment: Relevant answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9004937/is-there-a-good-reason-why-deleteby-does-not-have-its-most-general-type . Consistency with the type of `(==)` sounds like a plausible explanation.

Comment: simple to work around though (func . const)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `deleteBy` function is a generalization of `delete`, so it's helpful to take a look at `delete` first.

```
delete :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [a]
```

`delete` takes a value `Eq a => a`, then deletes the first occurance of that value from the `[a]` using the `(==)` from the `Eq` instance.

As with all the `*By` functions in [Data.List](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#g:23), the `Eq` constraint is removed and the programmer is required to provide their own replacement `(==)` function.

So removing the `Eq` constraint from `delete` and replacing it with the type of `(==)`, namely `a -> a -> Bool`, gives you the type of `deleteBy`.

In other words, it's for consistency with the rest of the `*By` operations in `Data.List`.

Comment: Which all suggests `deleteBy` should be given in terms of the more general function.

Answer (score 0):

As cdk and others point out. It is to generalize over the equality predicate.

The function you are asking for is 'delete elements in the list which match this predicate'. This is more akin to single element `filter`.

The `deleteBy` function is 'delete element x, but use this comparison operator instead of `(==)`'.